# How to configure .ghci file to import all loaded modules

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

let say I have a project which is just a bunch of Haskell modules with exercises. I'd like to provide a `.ghci` which automatically *imports* all modules into `ghci` scope. The problem is, I can not run `import` nor `:m +Module.Name` within `.ghci` file.

Clearly `cabal repl` is reading the `.ghci` file because options like the prompt are readed. Also it loads modules correctly, but it doesn't bring them into scope (only one gets imported). If I try to add `import OtherModule` to `.ghci` file, then I get the error

> module is member of hidden package fail-ghci
> Perhaps you need to add ‘fail-ghci’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.

But I can't add fail-ghci to the cabal file, because the library can't depend on itself!!

To reproduce. Create a simple cabal project. For example:

```
src
 |- Module1.hs  # include dummy function func1 :: Int
 |- Module2.hs  # include dummy function func2 :: Int
fail-ghci.cabal
.ghci
```

The content of `fail-ghci.cabal` is

```
name:           fail-ghci
version:        0.1.0.0
license:        BSD3
license-file:   LICENSE
build-type:     Simple

library
  exposed-modules:
      Module1
    , Module2
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

If you set `.ghci` as

```
:set prompt "> "  -- Set this option to ensure .ghci is readed by cabal repl
```

It will work fine and will bring `Module1.hs` into scope, so `func1` is available. But `Module2.hs` wont be in the scope, If I want to use it I'd need to execute `import Module2` or equivalent.

Now, I'd like this to happen automatically when running `cabal repl` because my project has many modules. The obvious (to me) choice is to modify `.ghci` as

```
:set prompt "> "  -- Set this option to ensure .ghci is readed by cabal repl

import Module2 -- Equivalent :m +Module2
```

But the ghci is unable to import the module, despite of that command woring correctly within ghci. What's the correct configuration to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem is simply that cabal executes the commands in your `.ghci` file *before* it loads the current project.
Indeed when I `cabal repl` in a similar project, the startup output is:

```
Build profile: -w ghc-9.0.2 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - fail-ghci-0.1.0.0 (first run)
Preprocessing library for fail-ghci-0.1.0.0..
GHCi, version 9.0.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/scratch/.ghci
[1 of 2] Compiling Module1          ( src/Module1.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Module2          ( src/Module2.hs, interpreted )
Ok, two modules loaded.
ghci>
```

My *guess* would be that this is probably because `cabal repl` starts a ghci session (which loads the `.ghci` file during startup) and then uses its API to load the project environment. (I was able to confirm that a `.ghci` file can import modules from packages that are fully installed, rather than from a current project being `cabal repl`d)

I don't know of any way to automatically execute commands after the project has been loaded. But you *can* have your `.ghci` file define a shortcut command that will import all the modules you want. That way you have at least have a single quick command to execute once you're in the ghci shell, instead of manually importing everything. Something like this:

```
:def loadall (const . pure) ":m + *Module1 *Module2"
-- or
:def loadall (const . pure) "import Module1 Module2"
-- or etc
```

Then you can just enter `:loadall` at the ghci prompt to get your modules imported.

Comment: Actually defining a macros is very helpfull. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One workaround I like is to add a new module to your project, perhaps called `DefaultRepl` or similar, that imports everything you want.  If you put this at the top of your exposed-modules list, then it will be loaded up when you run `cabal repl` and bring everything that it imports into scope.